# Split a string in python on a floating point number, if no floating point number found, split it on a number

Tags: python, regex, string, split, pattern-matching

I have a list of strings and I want to split each string on a floating point number. If there is no floating point number in the string, I want to split it on a number.
It should only split once and return everything before and after it separated by commas.

Input string:

```
['Naproxen  500  Active ingredient  Ph Eur',
 'Croscarmellose sodium  22.0 mg Disintegrant  Ph Eur',
 'Povidone K90  11.0   Binder 56 Ph Eur',
 'Water, purifieda',
 'Silica, colloidal anhydrous  2.62  Glidant  Ph Eur',
 'Magnesium stearate  1.38  Lubricant  Ph Eur']
```

Expected output:

```
['Naproxen',  '500',  'Active ingredient  Ph Eur',
 'Croscarmellose sodium',  '22.0 mg',  'Disintegrant  Ph Eur',
 'Povidone K90',  '11.0',  'Binder  Ph Eur',
 'Water, purified',
 'Silica, colloidal anhydrous',  '2.62',  'Glidant  Ph Eur',
 'Magnesium stearate',  '1.38',  'Lubricant  Ph Eur']
```

Comment: [`split('  ')`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Comment: `'Povidone K90',  '11.0',  'Binder  Ph Eur',` seems like incorrect splitting based on your description

Comment: @CoderCharmander Re-read the question.  This isn't asking for a simple split on whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this `re.split` option:

```
inp = 'Croscarmellose sodium  22.0 mg Disintegrant  Ph Eur'
parts = re.split(r'\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+', inp, 1)
print(parts)
```

This prints:

```
['Croscarmellose sodium', '22.0', 'mg Disintegrant  Ph Eur']
```

The idea is to split on this regex pattern:

```
\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+
```

This matches a number, with optional decimal component, surrounded by whitespace.  Note that we place parentheses around the number, since we do not want to consume it in the split.  Also note carefully that `re.split` is being used with its third parameter set to 1, which tells Python to split only once.

Comment: thanks a lot. But it is not working in this scenario `Hypromellose 6 mPas  31.50  Film former  Ph Eur`. the expected output here is `'Hypromellose 6 mPas',  '31.50',  'Film former  Ph Eur'`. Can you please help with this. Basically I want to match floating numbers first and only if there isnt a floating value match on an  integer

Comment: No, the output in this case is `['Hypromellose', '6', 'mPas 31.50 Film former Ph Eur']`, [see the demo here](https://rextester.com/WKJS64328).

Comment: Can I get this output as `'Hypromellose 6 mPas', '31.50', 'Film former Ph Eur'`? maybe put this in a if else condition to first match floats and if not found match on integer?

Comment: Can you please help me with the regex to only match float and another regex to only match integer so that I can put it in an ifelse and solve this?

Comment: You should open a new question.

Comment: Can you please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057011/get-all-values-before-a-decimal-number-an-integer-from-a-list-of-strings-in-py